# How to bind properties from DataContext while Itemssource is binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind a `RadioButton` with a property in a view model，but it seems to be binding with `ItemSource` now. I still need `ItemsSource` to get my `DataGrid` view items, so how can I fix it?

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[0]}" ItemsSource="{Binding LimitItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="55" Header="Select">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--radiobutton binding from datacontext-->
                    <RadioButton Checked="{Binding SetLimitCommand}" GroupName="Setting" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="120"
            Binding="{Binding MeasItem}"
            Header="MeasureItem" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Checked` is an event. You can add an event handler defined in code-behind to it, but you cannot bind it, it will throw an exception at runtime.

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo` to type `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`.

You can instead bind the `Command` property of the `RadioButton`. The data context of the each cell in the template column will be set to the current item for the row in the `ItemsSource`. This means that you have to use a `RelativeSource` binding in order to refer to the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`.

```
<RadioButton Command="{Binding DataContext.SetLimitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" GroupName="Setting" />
```

If you really need to bind a command to an event, you could use the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) NuGet package (which is a replacement for `System.Windows.Interactivity`) like this.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Setting">
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetLimitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the ItemsSource Property, all subsequent Bindings refer to the current Item's Properties. So in this case the Property SetLimitCommand is expected to be part of your Item-Type.
To bind the command to the ViewModel you could use [RelativeSource-Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0)

```
<RadioButton Checked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.SetLimitCommand}" GroupName="Setting" />
```

Anyway, I never tried to bind a Command to an Event... I'd prefer to bind to the Command Property, then you can pass the current item as CommandParameter too.